# Linux Mint 17.1 tar backup error

Tags: linux, backup, linux-mint, tar

I've used the below script successfully with ubuntu 12.04. Now I did a fresh install to Linux mint 17.1 and I can't get the tar backup script to work no more. it gives an error:

Here's the script, tried running outside the script and the tar works:

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date +%F)
HOST=$(hostname)

echo "------------- backing up $HOST ------------------"

sudo su - user -c "tar cvpzf /FILES/Media/Programs/Mint/Backup/$HOST$TODAY.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/FILES/Media/Programs/Mint/Backup/$HOST$TODAY.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/FILES --exclude=/sys --exclude=/BACKUP --exclude=/MEDIA /"

echo "------------- Finished ------------------"
```

Give's this error:

```
: not found/backup.sh: 2: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
: not found/backup.sh: 5: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
 ------------------ng up mint-server
: not found/backup.sh: 7: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /\r: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
: not found/backup.sh: 9: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
------------- Finished ------------------
```

Why is the script not working in Mint 17.1?

Comment: looks like a  simple   cp -ra /home/$username/*   //backup mountpoint  | tar -cvpf  foo.bar  would be  better with those --excludes and as for the  init.d  fails  mint and ubuntu 14.04  (which its based on are  moving to sysD  make those   initctl   pointers and  voila...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning!

I'm not sure why your script fails on Mint 17.1 but works on Ubuntu 12.04 - but I believe Ubuntu 12.04 uses `upstart` and Mint 17.1 uses `systemd` so it'll be based on that. Given the errors it looks like the script is being run by /bin/sh, though I believe this is linked to /bin/dash, which should be able to parse your script...

Is your script `/etc/init.d/backup.sh`? Your script is not actually a proper LSB compliant init script; init scripts must declare their dependencies with a header block, and respond to the **start**, **stop**, **reload**, etc. commands - a good description is in the Debian Wiki [LSBInitScripts](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts). If you have an `/etc/rc.local` script then run your script from there. It's the proper place to put user scripts which should be run after init has completed working through the runlevels.

I believe Mint 17 uses systemd by default, so if you don't have an `rc.local` you will need to create it and add a systemd service by creating `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service` containing:

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local
TimeoutSec=0
StandardInput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then running

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Any other custom boot scripts you use should be run from here. Of course you could create a separate systemd service to run your backup using the above as a skeleton, modified accordingly.

HTH!

Comment: Hi Hoji, thanks for replying. I actually found a solution for this and it was to run and script as bash and not with sh. But before running the script I used dos2unix to convert the script to unix compability.

Comment: Aah I see, from your errors it did look like your script was being run by sh, though I'm not sure how that happened from the init process - I've edited the answer to reflect that. Anyway, if you did find the answer useful it'd be great if you accepted the answer! All the best.